# What's the correct way to install st in Void Linux?

Tags: software-installation, package-management, configuration, void-linux

I wish to install [st](https://st.suckless.org/) in Void Linux. This program's configuration is made at compile time however. Void linux has this package in their repository, and I'm wondering if it is possible to use `xbps-install` somehow with my own configuration, or if the only way to configure it is by downloading the source and compiling it manually.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add a bit of context. First, what is `st`? Second, what kind of thing do you need to configure? If this is a program that is written in a compiled language and you need to set compile-time options then yes, you will need to compile manually. But the details will depend on exactly what you need.

Comment: @terdon Added a link that explains what `st` is. It is a program written in a C and the only way to configure it is with compile-times options, so I guess your comment answers my question.

Comment: In void and other distros I just compile suckless programs manually and install them under /usr/local. Since this doesn't use xbps, it doesn't exactly answer your question, but still, it's a lot easier and works in every distro.

Comment: @AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA my comment kinda sorta answers, but not really. I am not familiar with `xbps-install` so I cannot guarantee that there is no way of passing compile options. I doubt it, but if this is a package manager like emerge or pacman which also compile, it is possible that such an option exists. It will probably be simpler to just compile from source though.

Comment: @terdon Yeah, xbps is the package manager for void linux. Void has some similarities to Arch in that by default all packages are distributed as binaries, but it isn't too hard to build packages yourself from source. Usually you start by cloning the package definitions from https://github.com/void-linux/void-packages and then follow the instructions in the repo's README

Answer (score 1):

There is no correct way, since st is configured at build time, using the package doesn't make much sense.

There are two options:

- Build st manually.
- Build st with your configuration and patches using xbps-src.

To build st using `xbps-src` you first need to clonse the [void-packages](https://github.com/void-linux/void-packages) repository. Then you copy your patches into `srcpkgs/st/patches` and you configuration header to `srcpkgs/st/files/config.h` inside of the void-packages repository.

The package can be build with `./xbps-src pkg st`, to install the package you specify your local repository: `xbps-install -R hostdir/binpkgs st`.